# Pagination not adding the class

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2

I am using pagination and here is the code

```
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['first_link'] = 'First';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</div>';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<div>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</div>';
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a>';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'blog';
        $config['total_rows'] = $Count;
        $config['per_page'] = 2;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

And use

```
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

to invoke the pagination.

But the class `class="pagination"` is not adding for the `<ul>`.

I am getting only the below in the page source

```
<ul><a href="http://localhost/blog" data-ci-pagination-page="0">&lt;</a><li><a href="http://localhost/blog" data-ci-pagination-page="0">1</a></li><li class="active"><a>2</a></li><li><a href="http://localhost/blog/4" data-ci-pagination-page="4">3</a></li><a href="http://localhost/blog/4" data-ci-pagination-page="4">&gt;</a></ul>
```

So, How can i make the class appear so i can have `<ul class="pagination">` ?

Comment: where did you told to add class pagination?I think the answers will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Missing In Your Code**

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
$config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
```

**Bootstrap Codeigniter Pagination**

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = base_url('blog');
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('blog'); 
$config['uri_segment'] = 2; 
$config['per_page'] = 8;
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['num_links'] = "16";

$config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
$config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
$config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
$config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
$config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
$config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

[Codeigniter Pagination Library User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/pagination.html)

Second set routes in config/route.php

```
$route['blog'] = "blog"; May need blog/index

$route['blog/(:any)'] = "blog/$1"; May need blog/index
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your full tag open array element

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
```